# HTML page with ajax, can't seem to implement RGraph

Tags: php, html, ajax, rgraph

I'm building a basic webpage with a static header and footer.
On the left side, I have a menu.
When I press a menu button an ajax request is made and on the right side DIV I update my text.

menu01 - menu01.php 
contains php code with some Mysql results, this works fine.
I think this works fine, because it's all textual output.

menu02 - Menu02.php
contains html code to display RGraph, some text is being displayed OK in the right DIV, but the graph doesn't display.
The menu02.php file displays fine when I call this file directly.

I figured out, an RGraph output from a php file isn't xml data that I can use to update my right-side DIV of the page. ajax only suspect to receive some text, right?
So I must find another way to dynamicaly update my page and show different kinds of things on the right DIV, without reloading my whole page.
With this information I think I know why it doesn't work, but I don't know how to get the result I'm looking for. Does anyone have a clue where to look for?

Pieces of code:

index.html :

```
    <script src="./js/ajax.js"></script>

 <section id="sidebar">
     <nav>
      <ul>
        <li>  <button onclick="goto_menu1()">Menu 1</button> </li>
        <li>  <button onclick="goto_menu2()">Menu 2</button> </li>
      </ul>
     </nav>
 </section>
```

ajax.js :

```
 function goto_menu1()
    {
      var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
      }
      xmlHttp.open("GET", "./menu01/menu01.php", true);
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }

 function goto_menu2()
    {
      var xmlHttp = getXMLHttp();
      xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = function()
      {
        if(xmlHttp.readyState == 4)
        {
          HandleResponse(xmlHttp.responseText);
        }
      }
      xmlHttp.open("GET", "./menu02/menu02.php", true);
      xmlHttp.send(null);
    }
```

Comment: I think I've found my missing piece.
I should use an iframe to load the right side of my page, right?
I've got it working, but I'm not sure this is the best solution

Comment: Hmm, An iframe is a quick fix for my problem right now,
but I don't think it's the best choice.

Answer (score 0):

In the end it was all a matter of loading the right js on the right pages.
And calling the right jquery code for rgraph.

As I had a doubt on getting an RGraph (or other js module) loaded in a dynamic created div, I've now made it working.
How?

```
index.html :
load js rgraph module
call a js function for updating div

js function:
open a php page, generate data and set up the html layout
next, check-document-ready, run jquery rgraph call
```

I hope it gives some hope to those who have the same search :)